QT QML QSerial Port Needs Putty / External terminal to work
I have an app communicating with external device through COMPORT. Using teraTerm, I get the data well. On QT i get and parse the data well (and can also can send successfully). However, if I do not open Putty / teraTerm first, QT Finds the port, tells me it's opened but the SIGNAL SLOT never fires (QObject::connect(comPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSerial()));)
I can confirm that I can send data but can not receive (unless I open Putty/teraTerm before).
I guess it comes from the comPort init but I can't find any information.
Thanks !
class C_SerialPortManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit C_SerialPortManager(QObject *parent = nullptr);

...
signals:

private slots:
    void readSerial();

private:
    QSerialPort *comPort;
...
};

C_SerialPortManager::C_SerialPortManager(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    comPort = new QSerialPort(parent);
    qDebug() << (serialPortInit(comPort) == true ? "init Success" : " init Failure");
}

bool C_SerialPortManager::serialPortInit(QSerialPort * comPort)
{
    bool BMS_IS_AVAILIABLE = false;
    //
    //  For each available serial port
    foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
    {
        BMS_IS_AVAILIABLE = true; //    BMS is available on this port
        BMS_PORT_NAME = serialPortInfo.portName();
    }
    if(BMS_IS_AVAILIABLE)
    {
        qDebug() << "Found the port : " << BMS_PORT_NAME;

        comPort->setPortName(BMS_PORT_NAME);
        comPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
        comPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        comPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
        comPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        comPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        if (!(comPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)))
        {
            qDebug() << "Error String : "<< comPort->errorString();
            return(false);
        }

        qDebug() << "Connect Signal Slot :" << QObject::connect(comPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSerial()));
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Couldn't find the correct port.";
        timedOutSerial();
        return(false);
    }
    connect(&timerTimeoutSerial, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){timedOutSerial();});
    timerTimeoutSerial.start(500);
    return(true);
}

I tried going back to very simple code, same happens.
I tried different baudrates / comPort settings.
Without opening Putty / teraTerm first :
Found the port :  "COM6"
Connect Signal Slot : true
init Success

With opening Putty / teraTerm first :
Found the port :  "COM6"
Connect Signal Slot : true
init Success


What happens if you add comPort->setDataTerminalReady(true); after the open() call? It could be that the remote device you are communicating with expects hardware flow control at least to a certain extent, and since you disable it, you never tell the other side that you want to receive data from them. And perhaps PuTTY automatically sets this setting, regardless of hardware flow control?

Thanks a lot @chris_se ! It works perfectly ! Never thought of this !
